# Word for "those of the other side of a division"

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider:

> These challenges result in a division of the female members of society: there are those who chose to continue with the parasitic life, and those who reject it and strive for transcendence. The transcendents have no solidarity with the [members of the other side/division]

Is there such a word for this?

Comment: In this context, I would use the descriptor itself. "Parasites". The transcendents have no solidarity with the _parasites_. Only because you have already described the groups themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use **rest, remnants or the juxtaposed**

**Rest**
[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rest)

> Something that remains over : remainder

**Remnants**
[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remnant)

> Things left when others are gone

**juxtaposed**
[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juxtaposed)

> placed side by side for a contrasting comparison

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with "**Dissenters**", as with Supreme Court Justices' written opinions that go against the majority decision.

Answer (score 0):

***the Other***, (Capitalized) definition 2c from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/other)

> often Other:  A person or thing considered to represent or epitomize
>   difference or an outgroup. Used with the

***The Other*** (Capitalized).  I wish this reference explained it in simpler English, but here goes, from [Wikipedia, other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other):

> In phenomenology, the terms **the Other** and the Constitutive Other each
>   identify a cumulative, constituting factor in the self-image of a
>   person—the acknowledgement of being real. As such, **the Other** is
>   dissimilar to and the opposite of the Self, of Us, and of the Same.
>   **Otherness**, the characteristics of **the Other**, is the state of being
>   different from and alien to the social identity of a person and to the
>   identity of the Self. Another way of describing **"The Other"** is to
>   portray oneself at the centre of focus and **"The Other"** on the outside. (emphasis added)

Is your example a quotation from someone?  It seems overstated, to put it mildly.

Comment: it's a discussion of Simone de Beauvoir, with regard to her concept of Otherness, but to use Other in this context would be invalid given how specifically she develops the Other -- it's not other women, from the perspective of a woman.

Comment: @socrates OHHHhhhhh!  You just made clear to me something I "learned" when I was studying Dante's Divine Comedy, about how his entire ascension through Hell and Purgatory to reach Heaven was _really_ all centered around his earthly and spiritual love for the woman, Beatrice (much prettier in Italian).  Okay, but the professor always stressed Dante's symbolic journey of crossing to learn and thereby apprehend the notion of "**the Other**" in its entirety — i.e., Beatrice and how earthly love aspires to heavenly love. I get it now..coooool.  Thanks!

Comment: AH-HA!  So, since @socrates' question centers around a difference dividing the _female_ population, "**the Other**" wouldn't be appropriate because it indicates a distinction far beyond the differences separating the camps.  "**The Other**" is a challenge to the limits of human cognizance, whereas the differences between the women are knowable to both sides, however incompatible their ethoses may be.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were asking for a generic word (e.g. "the others"), but for that specific sentence you could say, "the parasites." It's harsh (IMO ridiculously harsh) language, but I'm echoing it from the previous sentence: "transcendence" becomes "transcendents" so "parasitic" could become "parasites".